# How to make 2 jQuery functions work?

Tags: jquery, function

I have 2 jQuery functions on my website: a fotoslider and a Scrollit function. But I can only use one function because the other won't work. It depends on which one I put at the bottom.

I have barely knowledge about jQuery but I need those functions on my site.

The function that is working here is the fotoslider because it's at the bottom.

Html:

```
<link href="ppgallery/css/ppgallery.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="ppgallery/css/dark-hive/jquery-ui-1.8.6.custom.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.6/jquery-ui.min.js"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="ppgallery/js/ppgallery.js"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#gallery').ppGallery();
});
```

the script file for the Scrollit Function:

```
$(function(){
  $.scrollIt();
});

$(document).ready(function() {  
    var stickyNavTop = $('#menu').offset().top;  

    var stickyNav = function(){  
        var scrollTop = $(window).scrollTop();  

        if (scrollTop > stickyNavTop) {   
            $('#menu').addClass('sticky');  
        } else {  
            $('#menu').removeClass('sticky');   
        }  
    };  

    stickyNav();  

    $(window).scroll(function() {  
        stickyNav();  
    });  
});
```

PS: Fotoslider was a plugin

Comment: You have two versions of jquery `1.4` and `1.8`, this is not allowed this way you have to use only one of it. so you can go for the `1.8`.

Comment: @Jai is right i think remove the second file and check

Comment: Hi thnx for reply. But when i remove <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js"></script> the fotoslider won't work fully anymore

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use jquery [no-conflict](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.noConflict/)

```
var $j = jQuery.noConflict();
```

Now you can use $j instead of $ in your jquery code.

There are always chances of conflict between these javascript libraries.